# How to send events from electron to react components only after all components are ready?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, use-effect

I have an electron app and I'm trying to use ReactJs with it. I have code in `main.js` that  sends some data on `dom-ready` event:

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('dom-ready', function () {
    dao.getIncomes(function (data) {
        mainWindow.webContents.send('income-data', data);
    });
}
```

Then I have React component, where I'm trying to set a listener for this event:

```
useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.on('income-data', function (event, data) {
        // some code
    });
}, []);
```

Sometimes, a component init this effect only when the event has already sent. And listener doesn't receive this data.

How do I set the listener correctly in this case?  O may be I should send events later, on some other event, instead of `dom-ready`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think first you should tell the electron the function in effect is being Execute。

```
const { ipcMain } = require('electron')
ipcMain.on('react-effect-executed', (event, arg) => {
  dao.getIncomes(function (data) {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('income-data', data);
  });
})

useEffect(() => {
    ipcRenderer.send('react-effect-executed', '');
    ipcRenderer.on('income-data', function (event, data) {
        // some code
    });
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, it's correct way, but I have many components and many events. So, in each component, which want to receive some data, I should send some "im-ready" event and process it event in main.js. It can get too complicated pretty quickly

Comment: In my opinion, my solution above is only one line more than the code in your question. Anyway, electron itself does not know when the various components of react are rendered.